# DateSerial in VBScript and .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, vbscript

In VBScript I have code:

```
someLongValue = CLng(DateSerial(2011, 11, 1))
```

and in that case someLongValue equals to 40848.

How can I do same cast in C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateTime.ToOADate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) should return what you're looking for:

```
int oleValue = (int)new DateTime(2011, 11, 1).ToOADate();
```

Comment: Note that DateTime will throw an exception if the month is not between 1 and 12 and if the day does not fit in the month. The VB6 DateSerial won't crash in those cases. With DateSerial, this expression is perfectly valid: DateSerial(2011, -5, 543)